# How do you return the value of a Property in a custom class

Tags: vb.net

I have a custom vb,net class named Location with multiple properties.

Example

Class = Location

Property = Street

Value = "Main St"

Property = City

Value = "AnyTown"

Property = Country

Value = "USA"

Through reflection I can get the names of each property:

```
Public Function GetLocationValue(ByRef sLocation)    
Dim sTable As New ProjectSchema.Location
sTable = sLocation
For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In sTable.GetType().GetProperties()
        If p.CanRead Then
           Console.WriteLine(p.Name)
        End If
Next
End Function
```

Results:

p.Name = Street

p.Name = City

p.Name = Country

How can I get the value of each p.Name and return "Main St", "AnyTown" o "USA"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to get the value from the property info:

```
Dim val as Object
For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In sTable.GetType().GetProperties()
    If p.CanRead Then
       Console.WriteLine(p.Name)
       val = p.GetValue(sTable, Nothing)
       Console.WriteLine(val)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Now, how can I make this function so that I can use it for other custom classes?

Comment: @gspeedtech.  Just wrap it in a Function call (potentially a Shared one...)

Answer (score 2):

Where p is your PropertyInfo object.

```
p.GetValue (sTable, Nothing)
```